# Is there a maximum amount of shapekeys I can have?

Tags: mesh, shape-keys

Is there a maximum amount of shape keys I can have for a mesh, or is it unlimited?

Answer (score 0):

Max length of the name is 63.
The combination of name is $ 144697^{63}= 12851392879591122911761589304575794295758797271787940570926311614287919224341791971469577328053770301824716271030055608943648883125919393360195551682522819982095389316489211601257250722083879440804630034307102152166481391108662198091375635962541703419882552734342779293835756366410618237248180266663032403968561741920274718473$

Name cannot repeat in blender, So there exist a maximum amount of object you can have.